# bootstrap align 3 images in a column

Tags: html, css

I want to make the 3 image inside a column when resolution is small. 
When using col-md-4 it will become one row. how to make it with one column event the screen resolution is in small size.

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top:50px">


<div class="col col-md-4" >
  <a href="gasoline.aspx"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.eremedia.com/uploads/2015/05/stackoverflow.png"  width="200px" height="120px" class="center-block img-fluid" /></a>
  <p class="text-center" style="    text-transform: capitalize;
font-size: .85em;
font-weight: 600;
line-height: 1.5em;
color: #212121;
text-decoration: none;">A PRODUCTS</p>
</div>

<div class=" col col-md-4">
  <a href="diesel.aspx"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.eremedia.com/uploads/2015/05/stackoverflow.png" width="200px" height="120px" class="center-block img-fluid" /></a>
  <p class="text-center" style="    text-transform: capitalize;
font-size: .85em;
font-weight: 600;
line-height: 1.5em;
color: #212121;
text-decoration: none;">B PRODUCTS</p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-auto col-md-4">
  <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.eremedia.com/uploads/2015/05/stackoverflow.png" width="200px" height="120px" data-modal="#modal-youtube" class="center-block img-fluid" style="cursor: pointer; " />
  <p class="text-center" style="    text-transform: capitalize;
font-size: .85em;
font-weight: 600;
line-height: 1.5em;
color: #212121;
text-decoration: none;">COPORATE VIDEO</p>
</div>
```

Below is the example code
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/wx52fyt8/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first, you should use [Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid) correctly:

- Rows must be placed within a `.container`;
- Columns should be placed within a `.row` (in your case), and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

If you want to get different width of the columns in dependence of screen size, just use additional grid classes for the columns:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In result each column will fill full row width on small and extra small devices, and 1/3 of the row width in other cases.

**Note:** while you are using Bootstrap 3.3.7, *the `.col` and 
`.col-md-auto` classes are defined in Bootstrap since version 4.0*.

Comment: @Michael , ok, I have clarified my answer, try again, please.